# How do I make the border x distance away from image?

Tags: ios, swift

I want a border around my image, but I want the border to be a certain distance from the actual image. Right now it creates a border right around the image. How would I do this?

```
 let image = UIImage(named: "WhitePeeyr")!
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    let padding = CGFloat(20)
    let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100 + 2*padding, 40 + 2*padding)


    imageView.frame = CGRectInset(frame, padding, padding)
    imageView.frame.origin.y = view.frame.size.height - 542
    imageView.frame.origin.x = (self.view.bounds.size.width - imageView.frame.size.width) / 2.0
    view.addSubview(imageView)

    let borderView = UIView(frame: frame)
    borderView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    borderView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    borderView.clipsToBounds = true
    view.addSubview(borderView)
```

Comment: Maybe consider replace imageView.frame.origin.x line with centre alignment constraints

Answer (score 0):

You will need two separate views (or layers):

```
let image = UIImage(named: "image")!
let padding = CGFloat(20)
let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width + 2*padding, image.size.height + 2*padding)

let borderView = UIView(frame: frame)
borderView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
borderView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
borderView.clipsToBounds = true
view.addSubview(borderView)

let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
imageView.frame = CGRectInset(frame, padding, padding)
view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: How would I adjust the size of the image?

Comment: By changing the frame

Comment: I updated my code, the image changes position, but the border says at some point.